# PHP: include files without composer

Tags: php, include, composer-php

I have to check the `InAppPurchases` receipts with my PHP server.
I would use [this script](https://github.com/aporat/store-receipt-validator) in order to achieve my goal.

I'm running on a shared hosting server, so I'm not able to install or use `composer`. How can I still use and include the above mentioned PHP script?

I already included the following lines:

```
require '../lib/validate_inapp_purchase/iTunes/PurchaseItem.php';
require '../lib/validate_inapp_purchase/iTunes/Response.php';
require '../lib/validate_inapp_purchase/iTunes/Validator.php';
use ReceiptValidator\iTunes\Validator as iTunesValidator;
```

But the script throws the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found in /homepages/11/htdocs/app/lib/validate_inapp_purchase/iTunes/Validator.php on line 130
```

Comment: You have to include GuzzleHttp\Client the same way you are doing with all other files.

Answer (score 2):

Use `composer` locally (on your machine) and then upload everything (including `vendor` folder) to the hosting server.